# Is there any way to query postgres JSON/JSONB columns with ilike and indexing?

Tags: postgresql, json

I have a table called **user_data** where I have `JSON` column called **data** which can have any key that can be given by application users. Here I wanted to do `ilike` query with using proper index.

Since keys in JSON field are created by application users I can't create index for specific key. Also tried `JSONB` column as well, we can have index for `JSONB` but it will be used for only **equality** check. I could't get appropriate solution for querying JSON/JSONB with using proper indexing when using `ilike` operator.

**Note**: As of now table have **4 billion** rows. It will keep grow every day. I know partition/sharding may help me. But it would be better to know if there is any solution other than partition. Is any other data type like hstore solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using wildcards, or are you using ILIKE just to get its case insensitivity feature?

Comment: @jjanes I am using ilike.